# I'm trying to send data from a cell range to a discord chat channel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, discord

I'm trying to send data from a range of cells to a discord text channel. I have the webhook working. However, I can't seem to convert the cell data in the "message = messager" part of the code.

```
function postMessageToDiscord(message) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loot");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A12:N12");



  message = message || "range" ;

  var discordUrl = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/565294544682221617/l_mER5nwxITlaW-9g0qXZxZ0CDSWqLrHYXDcvcdyubC9VElWmbfbRTdwbQhVFdyVYxFq';
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. I need to convert the data coming in from the sheet.getRange to I guess a string to go in the message = message || "range" ;

Comment: Ok, and what does the web hook receive/what do you want it to receive?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to receive the data from this cell range.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not understanding what you're trying to do with your message = message line. It's checking if message is falsy and if it is then it sends the string "range". Do you mean to have the alternate as the variable range?

Comment: This is from google sheets by the way. I'm using google app script "javascript."

Comment: yes. The "range" string is a place holder. Im trying to have this script send the actual range from cells A12:N12 as the message. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRange` returns a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object.

From the docs we can see there's a [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) method which returns a two dimensional array containing the data in each cell.

So we can write a simple for loop like so:

```
var data = range.getValues();
var result = '';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var d = data[i];
   for (var j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
       result = result.concat(d[j]);
   }
}
```

then send the result var.

Comment: it says TypeError: Cannot call method "concat" of undefined.

Answer (score 2):

This is the final result.

```
function postMessageToDiscord(message) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loot");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A12:N12");

  var data = range.getValues();
  var result = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d = data[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
      result = result.concat(d[j]);
   }
}


  message = message || result ;

  var discordUrl = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/565294544682221617/l_mER5nwxITlaW-9g0qXZxZ0CDSWqLrHYXDcvcdyubC9VElWmbfbRTdwbQhVFdyVYxFq';
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```